# Mongodb : How to convert a collection to an array with MongoDB PHP Library?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am using MongoDB PHP Library to manipulate mongodb.
I queried some data from mongodb,and I want to convert the query result to an array,
because I want to insert the array into mysql.

for example,

```
    $collection = (new \MongoDB\Client)->test->articles;
    $cursor = $collection->find([],['projection' => ['_id' => 0]])
    $articles=$cursor->toArray();
    dd($articles);
```

I use `toArray()` to convert `$cursor` to an array , the result is like this:
[image]

The elements of the result are `BSONDocument`,they can not be inserted into mysql  correctly,what should I do?

Comment: `$cursor->toArray()`

Comment: or $array =  (array) $cursor;

Comment: @Alex Blex I want to save it into mysql. see my update.

Comment: Add the code that give you such result and don't use screenshots: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @Alex Blex . I updated my question,please see it again.thanks.